# typing on keyboard should effect keyboard on web

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee

I am making typing tutor web app for my college project. I want keyboard to be displayed in website and if i type any letter on keyboard that should highlight the key of web keyboard. So what technology should i use for displaying keyboard on web. I want to use java.

*any help is appreciated*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did we help you? If so, please pick an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Key Listeners for this.

Key events indicate when the user is typing at the keyboard. Specifically, key events are fired by the component with the keyboard focus when the user presses or releases keyboard keys. Please note these events will work only when your application has the System Focus.

```
1) Make sure the component's isFocusable method returns true. This state allows the component to receive the focus. For example, you can enable keyboard focus for a JLabel component by calling the setFocusable(true) method on the label.
2) Make sure the component requests the focus when appropriate. For custom components, implement a mouse listener that calls the requestFocusInWindow method when the component is clicked
```

Sample Code for Key Event Listener:

```
public class KeyEventDemo ...  implements KeyListener ... {
    ...//where initialization occurs:
        typingArea = new JTextField(20);
        typingArea.addKeyListener(this);

        //Uncomment this if you wish to turn off focus
        //traversal.  The focus subsystem consumes
        //focus traversal keys, such as Tab and Shift Tab.
        //If you uncomment the following line of code, this
        //disables focus traversal and the Tab events 
        //become available to the key event listener.
        //typingArea.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    ...
    /** Handle the key typed event from the text field. */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        displayInfo(e, "KEY TYPED: ");
    }

    /** Handle the key-pressed event from the text field. */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        displayInfo(e, "KEY PRESSED: ");
    }

    /** Handle the key-released event from the text field. */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        displayInfo(e, "KEY RELEASED: ");
    }
    ...
    private void displayInfo(KeyEvent e, String keyStatus){

        //You should only rely on the key char if the event
        //is a key typed event.
        int id = e.getID();
        String keyString;
        if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            keyString = "key character = '" + c + "'";
        } else {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            keyString = "key code = " + keyCode
                    + " ("
                    + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode)
                    + ")";
        }

        int modifiersEx = e.getModifiersEx();
        String modString = "extended modifiers = " + modifiersEx;
        String tmpString = KeyEvent.getModifiersExText(modifiersEx);
        if (tmpString.length() > 0) {
            modString += " (" + tmpString + ")";
        } else {
            modString += " (no extended modifiers)";
        }

        String actionString = "action key? ";
        if (e.isActionKey()) {
            actionString += "YES";
        } else {
            actionString += "NO";
        }

        String locationString = "key location: ";
        int location = e.getKeyLocation();
        if (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD) {
            locationString += "standard";
        } else if (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT) {
            locationString += "left";
        } else if (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT) {
            locationString += "right";
        } else if (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD) {
            locationString += "numpad";
        } else { // (location == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN)
            locationString += "unknown";
        }

        ...//Display information about the KeyEvent...
    }
}
```

Try [Java Docs/ tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for more help.

Comment: Any specific reason for your doubt? JSF is having a better performance bt Swing is also a tested approach and i used this long way back and didn't had performance issues.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/developing.html

Comment: please suggest me which technologies should i use for this application. I am good in core java.

Comment: I might not be the right person with educate credentials for this.I personally feel "JSF" is powerful and its api has abundant resources/way to accomplish such tasks effectively. Hope i was of any help for you. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Web pages end up running on client browsers, which understands only HTML, CSS and Javascript. You can accomplish this only with Javascript, with no server side code.

If you really want to play around and do it by Java code, I could suggest two (of many) approaches:

- Develop a taglib for use along with JSP pages. That Taglib would print a virtual keyboard on screen, and along with some javascript code, would listen to keyboard events and highlight them on the virtual keyboard (this is more of a hybrid solution).
- Play around with Google's GWT. It would let you create your virtual keyboard and event listeners entirely with java code, and result in a web page, without the need for you to develop HTML, CSS and Javascript. GWT basically gives you a way to construct a web page similar as creating a Swing GUI, and translates that to HTML, CSS and Javascript code.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit
http://www.gwtproject.org